# webdriver - select popup with getWindowHandles()

Tags: selenium, window-handles

I'm trying to switch focus on popup when appears but getWindowHandles().size() is returning just 1 window.

how to determine if I can switch to popup? or popup is not a new windows in my case

here is a part of code:

```
String parentWindowHandlerP = driver.getWindowHandle(); // save ID parent window
String subWindowHandlerP = null;

    // action to call popup
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("pt1:pt_region0:2:pt1:ilov1::lovIconId"))).click();

    Set<String> handlesP = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all windows
    Iterator<String> iteratorP = handlesP.iterator();
    while (iteratorP.hasNext()) {
        subWindowHandlerP = iteratorP.next();
    }
    // popup operations     
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:pt_region0:2:pt1:t1:_afrFltrc6::content")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:pt_region0:2:pt1:ilov1_afrLovDialogId::ok")).click();

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandlerP); // back na parent window
```

Comment: Is it an `alert` rather than a popup?

Comment: I was trying to do driver.switchTo().alert() but in error stacktrace I have that alert is not present.

Comment: Since you're saying that the number of windows remains as 1, I can't see that switching windows is going to help... Is your popup an `iframe` perhaps?

Comment: no, it's not iframe. I'm thinking that only solution is to insert thread.sleep() (maybe bad solution but it's only thing that I can do)

Comment: I try to use `webdriverwaits` as much as possible, sometimes I have to use `thread.sleep()` as well. "Whatever works" is sometimes the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    String parentWindowHandlerP = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
    // action to call popup
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("pt1:pt_region0:2:pt1:ilov1::lovIconId"))).click();

    while (driver.getWindowHandles().size() < 2) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String windowHandle : handles) {
        if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandlerP)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in my case with this part od code I can't pass this if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandlerP)) because parentWindow and popupWindow has same ID :(